# nextJS different theme for directory

Tags: next.js

I am having a small issue, I know I can use `_document.js` for /page however I need a different document layout for a directory. I am wondering how can I change the document theme/layout based on a sub directory.

I tried to make a new `_document.js` under the sub directory `/staff` however that did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a good question, indeed you can only create one custom `_document.js` (or `_document.ts` if you are using typescript). To change the structure of your DOM -- adding scripts, changing `<Head>` balises for SEO etc...

Since `_document.js` is the "root" of the DOM tree, it would not make sense to be able to overwrite this file in other subfolders.

However, if you need a different `Layout`, I would suggest to create a custom [`Layout`](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/layouts#single-shared-layout-with-custom-app) component that you can use whenever you need!  In your case, you can name it `StaffLayout`.

Note that your problem is a common use case and *Next.JS* even provided a [demo repository](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/layout-component) to help you achieve it.

eg.

```
// components/staffLayout.js

import Navbar from './navbar'
import Footer from './footer'

export default function StaffLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <>
      <Navbar />
      <main>{children}</main>
      <Footer />
    </>
  )
}
```

and then in your `/staff` directory

```
// pages/staff/backOffice.js

import StaffLayout from '../../components/staffLayout'

export default function BackOffice() {
  return (
    <StaffLayout>
      <>enter you code here</>
    </StaffLayout>
  )
}
```

If you need multiple `Layout`s, *Next.js* created a mechanism out-of-the-box that can even remove the need for using `StaffLayout` every-time. It is a little bit more advance so I will only [link the documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/layouts#per-page-layouts).

Comment: Thanks, the only issue is we have an audio player which is inside the _app.js as we need it to run on every page, the only area we don't need it is in the staff area. 

I guess while yes the above does work and I'll mark it as correct (thanks) I need to work out how to get the `ctx` asPage info and do an if statement inside the `_app.js` file, that unloads the audio player in the staff area. as the above and the link makes Ajax not really work well.

Comment: Hey! If think you have 2 solutions to manage this. For both you'll need to put your audio player of the `_app.js` into a Layout. solution 1 - In your `_app.js`, and you add an `if` statement as you suggested yourself to load the Layout -- you can have info of the Component's name in your `_app.js` params. 2 - You can use advance option per-page-layouts and add the Layout to every pages of your app. I think solution 1 may be better if you have an already big app but option 2 is more maintainable (According to me). Good luck! As for link that makes Ajax not works well I have no clues of why...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Next.js 13+, you can use layout.tsx file in that directory to apply the layout.

If you are using app router, you can use custom theme like below

```
export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  // Use the layout defined at the page level, if available
  const getLayout = Component.getLayout || ((page) => page)
 
  return getLayout(<Component {...pageProps} />)
}
```

Check out - https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/pages-and-layouts